# What is the correct way to refer to polkadot js api?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed several different spellings of the [polkadot js api](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api):

As a moderator I would like to know what the correct way to refer to this api is so that I can correct spelling mistakes such as this one:

> PolkaDotJS API

Found here:

- [How to get historical substrate (extrinsic, events, etc) data using polkaDotJS API](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/221/how-to-get-historical-substrate-extrinsic-events-etc-data-using-polkadotjs-a)

polkadotJS api? polkadot-js api? polkadot-js/api? @polkadot/api? polkadot js api? Polkadot JS?

Answer (score 1):

In the [Polkadot-JS API README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polkadot/api), it is written as:

> The **Polkadot-JS API** provides easy-to-use wrappers around JSONRPC calls that flow from an application to a node.

- `@polkadot/api`: this is a valid way to reference the [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polkadot/api), where `@polkadot` is the namespace for all of the packages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-at-prefix-on-npm-packages
- Polkadot-JS: this refers to all of the packages, not just the API. For example Polkadot-JS Apps, Polkadot-JS Extension, etc...

I personally write it as Polkadot JS with a space instead of a hyphen, because I don't think it really matters.